# Multiplication and Division with contract value

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, banking, remix

I am trying to insert a if-clause in the following contract to check if the withdrawal (it is a sample bank contract) is less than the 10% of the whole contracts value, i.e. of the complete bank. 
When I insert the code as below it gives me an error such as 
"UnimplementedFeatureError: Not yet implemented - FixedPointType."

What am I doing wrong?
Can you help me? 
Many thanks in advance!!

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract bank{
mapping (address => uint) private balance;
address public Owner;

function WithDrawMoreMoney(uint a) public{
    require (balance[msg.sender]>=0);
    require (address(this).balance>=0);
    require ((a) =< (address (this).balance)*(uint(1.1)));    // The problematic line
    balance[msg.sender]-=a;
    (msg.sender).transfer(a);
```

Comment: Fixed points are not supported by solidity https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#fixed-point-numbers

Answer (score 2):

> check if the withdrawal ... is less than [10%] of the whole [contract's] value

I think you just want this:

```
require(a <= address(this).balance / 10);
```

Your code multiplied by 1.1 when I think you meant 0.1, but either way Solidity only has integers. Dividing by 10 works. You also had a typo: `=<` instead of `<=`.

If you want to check some other percentage, like 23%:

```
require(a <= address(this).balance * 23 / 100);
```

Make sure to do the multiplication first, and always remember to guard against integer overflows.